# Countif for Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I need a formula for excel that says to countif (G3 >= BK (which is a date) and < BL3 (which is another date.

Countif the cell is equal to or greater than a cell, but less than another date(trying to count dates that are within the week of the first date, which begins on a Monday...

Comment: I think what you need is `COUNTIFS`

Comment: =COUNTIF(G3,">=$BK$3,"&">$BL$3")   I only want one count.  I'm not trying to get multiple counts if the cell falls within the week. I only want one count.

Comment: Countif usually uses a range of cells not a single cell.  with a single cell I would use AND: `=AND(G3>=$BK$3,G3<$BL$3)` which return TRUE/FALSE

Comment: That won't work.  I don't need false or true.  I'm actually looking for a way to count if it is within the range and not count otherwise.

Comment: So you want 1 or 0?  because one cell would return either 1 or 0.

Comment: Yes.  I want it to return a 1 or 0

Comment: `=--(AND(G3>=$BK$3,G3<$BL$3))` will return 1 or 0

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing but it's returning a 0 as if it's false, but it's actually a true statement.

Comment: Scott, it works.  I had the work cell in the formula.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this way because, Countif/Countifs needs Range of cells to evaluate:**

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A25,">="&B1,A2:A25,"<="&B2)
```

**Note,** Cell `B1` & `B2` contains Date value.

**Or if you want to check G3 for two Date values then it should be,**

```
=AND(G3>=$K$3,G3<$BL$3)
```

This will return TRUE if `G3 >= K3` or return FALSE.

**Or**

```
=IF(AND(G3>=$K$3,G3<$BL$3),1,2)
```

This will return `1` if `G3 is >= K3` otherwise return `2`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: What is wrong with the answer !!